# send sms from php- Enablex.io API authentication not working with provided API key

Tags: php, sms

I am using enablex.io to send SMS messages via PHP, I have included my given APP key with my POST request to the API endpoint, however I am receiving an authentication error.

But I have put
$apiKey = urlencode('your app key');

**My Code:**

```php
<?php
    // Account details
    $numbers = 'phone number';
    
    $var = '12345';
    $sender = urlencode('TXTLCL');
    $string = 'Dear user,'. $var.' is the OTP to sign-in to swulj.com - Thanks Team SWULJ ';
    $message = rawurlencode($string);
    $headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("your APP_ID:your APP_KEY") 
);
$data =array(
    
       'from'=> 'SWULJP',
       'body'=> $string,
       'direct'=> false,    
       'recipient'=> [    
            array(
                'to'=> $numbers,
               
        'body'=> 'This body supercedes with direct: true',
        'uuid'=> 'String'
            )
        ],
       'type'=> 'sms',
       'reference'=> 'XOXO',
       'validity'=> '30',
       'type_details'=> '',
       'data_coding'=> 'plain',
       'flash_message'=> false,
       
       'campaign_id'=> '25550516',
       'template_id'=> '1215'
);
    // Message details
    
     
    
     
    
    // Send the POST request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.enablex.io/sms/v1/messages/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    // Process your response here
    echo $response;
    ?>
```

**Response (Error):**

```json
{"result":0,"job_id":"617901d728665117a1656964"}
```

I have an `APP_ID` and an `APP_KEY` from enablex.io, I have tried both though neither work.
They say APP_key is the password and APP_ID is the login

Comment: According to the SMS API on [enablex.io](https://www.enablex.io/developer/sms-api/), you need to pass the API Key as headers, not in the POST body. You can do this with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`

Answer (score 0):

The APP ID and APP KEY is should be part of the Authorization header. Please refer to [this](https://www.enablex.io/developer/sms-api/). So to put this you should doing like this:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("APP_ID:APP_KEY") 
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: OK I changed accordingly, but still I get errors, I have edited my post

Comment: @remov, in PHP we use => instead : to point key value array.

Comment: still problems, check the edit

Comment: I have not given “scheduled_dt”: “2019-12-17T14:26:57+00:00”,
       “created_dt”: “2019-12-15T14:26:57+00:00”,-----Is that the problem. How can I give dt when I am not sure when I will send sms

Comment: @remov the value $data of curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); must string just wrap you $data using json_encode(), so it will be like curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

Comment: I changed my code, but did not get any sms

Comment: @remov it's still in queue you can check the delivery status also, please check the documentation.

Comment: I got the message after changing template id to 1215